# Application.OnKey does not work

Tags: excel, keypress, excel-2013, vba

I am trying to execute a sub, when I press a specific key in Excel 2013, using the `Application.OnKey` method.

I have the following code

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{r}", "MyEvent"
    Application.OnKey "{t}", "MyEvent"
    Application.OnKey "{x}", "MyEvent"
    Application.OnKey "{z}", "MyEvent"
End Sub

Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey "{r}"
    Application.OnKey "{t}"
    Application.OnKey "{x}"
    Application.OnKey "{z}"
End Sub

Public Sub MyEvent()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

When I press the keys the sub `MyEvent` does not executes. How can I modify the code to make it work?

---

**EDIT**: I want the keys to be pressed to be: `r`, `t`, `x`, and `z` instead of `ENTER`.

Comment: I have already tried recreating the solution, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I wan't to trigger the macro, when I press the key "r", "t", "z", and "x".

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Add the code to a module, save the workbook close then reopen it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

    Application.OnKey "r", "MyEvent"
    Application.OnKey "t", "MyEvent"
    Application.OnKey "x", "MyEvent"
    Application.OnKey "z", "MyEvent"

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    Application.OnKey "r"
    Application.OnKey "t"
    Application.OnKey "x"
    Application.OnKey "z"

End Sub

Public Sub MyEvent()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```